# Using a Third-Party Filter in AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am working on an AngularJS app. I am using [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme) in my views. For example, I have code that looks like this in my views:

```
<h3>Welcome { user.firstName | _.str: 'capitalize' }}</h3>
```

I need to use the capitalize function in the controller that's associated with this view. In an attempt to do that, I have the following:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $filter) {
    $scope.user = null;
    $scope.defaultValue = null;

    $scope.initialize = function() {
      $scope.user = getUser();
      $scope.defaultValue = $filter('capitalize')('my value');
    };
    $scope.initialize();
})
```

Everything works until I try to all the capitalize filter. What am I doing wrong? I get an error that says:

```
Unknown provider: capitalizeFilterProvider <- capitalizeFilter
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems odd that it works fine in my view but now my controller.

Comment: Where is your filter definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

register your filter as a dependency in your app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','capitalize']);
```

for more info look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

**EDIT:**
create the angular filter and use it as a wrapper for the underscore.string library:

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('capitalize', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return _.str.capitalize(input)
  };
});
```

in your template:

```
<h3>Welcome { user.firstName | capitalize }}</h3>
```

Comment: Looking at the underscore.string angular directive though, that doesn't work. Its odd. It uses _.str as the filter name. Then the name ('capitalize') then the parameters. I can't get it to work in the controller though.

Comment: create a filter and use it as a wrapper for the _str function